# Simplify Kotlin function with a lambda

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I have this function on `FooClass` class:

```
fun foo(id: Int, listener: Listener<JsonElement>) {
    enqueue(listener, apiService.getFoo(id))
}
```

This is the interface:

```
interface Listener<T> {
    fun onSuccess(result: T?)

    fun onFailure()
}
```

When I call it, I do this:

```
FooClass().foo(id, object : FooClass.Listener<JsonElement> {
    override fun onSuccess(result: JsonElement?) {}
    override fun onFailure() {}
})
```

I want to make a lambda to simplify when I make the call. Something like this:

```
fun foo {id ->
    // Perform onSuccess
    // Perform onFailure
}
```

I know this is basic, but I'm a mess... :-(

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Please show the `Listener<T>` definition.

Comment: `interface Listener<T> {
        fun onSuccess(result: T?)

        fun onFailure()
    }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use some tricks for that.

```
typealias SuccessCallback<T> = (T?) -> Unit
typealias FailureCallback = () -> Unit

inline fun FooClass.foo(id: Int, crossinline success: SuccessCallback<JsonElement?>, crossinline failure: FailureCallback) {
    foo(id, object: FooClass.Listener<JsonElement> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: JsonElement?) = success(result)
        override fun onFailure() = failure()
    })
}
```

Now you should be able to call

```
FooClass().foo(id, 
    success = { result: JsonElement? -> 
        ... 
    }, 
    failure = { 
    }
)
```

Comment: Technically if you own `FooClass` then the gist is that you need to be able to provide two separate lambdas, and not just a single listener. But if you don't own FooClass, then you *should* be able to use this extension function and can pretty much throw it anywhere you want. `typealias`es must be top-level, inside a file, but outside of class. They can also be `private`. If the function is top-level, then you can easily import it.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation :-). I have this error inside the Extension fun: `object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member. Required: Int, Found: <T>`

Comment: I was so focused on the `crossinline` that I forgot to add the `id: Int` parameter. Fixed.

Comment: I have a `Type mismatch`... `Required FooClass.Listener<JsonElement>` but `Found: <T>`. I have updated the question... It is possible the interface was needed.

Comment: Well.. anyway I have found a valid solution thank you to you. I am going to write it. :-)

Comment: I had to get home and try it out, and yeah, I did have to remove the `T` stuff. It was pretty close though, I think you are missing the crossinlines in your answer. Crossinline should result in better bytecode, afaik.

Comment: Yes, it is better and very pretty :-). I am going to put it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @EpicPandaForce I have found a solution. It is this:

```
fun foo(id: Int, success: (JsonElement?) -> Unit, error: () -> Unit) {
    enqueue(apiService.getFoo(id), object : Listener<JsonElement> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: JsonElement?) = success(result)

        override fun onFailure() = error()
    })
}
```

*I have refactored the order of the parameters on the* `enqueue` *function to be more readable.*

To call the function is as simple as this:

```
    FooClass().foo(id,
            success = { result ->
                // Handle success result
            },
            error = {
                // Handle error
            }
    )
```